# Counting how many times one value is in the same series of another df

Tags: python, pandas

I've been having some difficulty seeing how many time one value exists in the same column but of another df. Here's what I'm working with:

```
data1 = {
    "Col 1": ['a','b','c'],
    "Col 2": [1,2,3]
}

data2 = {
    "Col 1": ['f','a','b'],
    "Col 2": [4,5,6]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

[image: df1]
[image: df2]

Now I have this block of code to see how many times a value in col 1 in df1 also appears in col 1 of df2. (I only have a col 2 because I want to show how I want to iterate without using iterrows):

```
count = 0 #Setting the variable count
for row in df1['Col 1']: #Iterating through each row.
    if row in df2['Col 1']:
        count += 1 #Increasing count by 1 every time there's a repeated value.
print("Count:", count)
```

When I run this, my count returns as 0, when it should be 2, since both df1['Col 1'] and df2['Col 2'] both share 'a', and 'b'.

I'm sure this is a minor error, but I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to check if a column contains a certain value in pandas, you need to add `.values`. Without it, you are creating a splice of the dataframe with the column and the indices, like so:

```
print(df2['Col 1'])
```

[image: Print of spliced dataframe]


Changing this to `print(df2['Col 1'].values)` yields a list of the contents of the column: `['f' 'a' 'b']`, allowing your `if` statement to find your strings in that list.
Therefore, updating your code to:

```
count = 0 #Setting the variable count
for row in df1['Col 1']: #Iterating through each row.
    if row in df2['Col 1'].values:
        count += 1 #Increasing count by 1 every time there's a repeated value.
print("Count:", count)
```

Prints out: `Count:2`, your expected answer. More info on finding values in columns can be found [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-check-column-contains-a-value-in-dataframe/).

Answer (score 0):

Just find `set` intersection between the respective columns of dataframes:

```
df1.apply(lambda x: len(set(x) & set(df2[x.name])))
```

---

```
Col 1    2
Col 2    0
dtype: int64
```